# Destroy Widget in Tk not working

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have a Pertl Tk code, I want to close the main window and open another but after the first window is closing again when second window gets open te first window also appears.

The code

```
 use strict;
 use Tk;

 my $mw;

 #Calling the welcome_window sub
 welcome_window();

 sub welcome_window{

    #GUI Building Area
    $mw = new MainWindow; 

    my $frame_header = $mw->Frame();
    my $header = $frame_header -> Label(-text=>"Molex Automation Tool");
    $frame_header -> grid(-row=>1,-column=>1);
    $header -> grid(-row=>1,-column=>1);

    my $region_selected = qw/AME APN APS/;

    my $frame_sub_header = $mw->Frame();
    my $sub_header = $frame_sub_header -> Label(-text=>"Region Selection");
    $frame_sub_header -> grid(-row=>2,-column=>1);
    $sub_header -> grid(-row=>2,-column=>1);


    my $frame_region = $mw->Frame();
    my $label_region = $frame_region -> Label(-text=>"Region:");
    my $region_options = $frame_region->Optionmenu(
        -textvariable => \$region_selected,
        -options  => [@regions],
    );
    $frame_region -> grid(-row=>3,-column=>1);
    $label_region -> grid(-row=>3,-column=>1);
    $region_options -> grid(-row=>3,-column=>2);

    my $frame_submit = $mw->Frame();
    my $submit_button = $frame_submit->Button(-text    => 'Go!',
                  -command => \&outside,
            );
    $frame_submit -> grid(-row=>4,-column=>1,-columnspan=>2);
    $submit_button -> grid(-row=>4,-column=>1,-columnspan=>2);

    MainLoop;
}

#This sub is just made to close the main window created in Welcome_Wiondow() sub and call the second_window()

sub outside{

    $mw -> destroy;
    sleep(5);
    second_window();
}


sub second_window{

    my $mw2 = new MainWindow;
    my $frame_header2 = $mw2->Frame();
    my $header2 = $frame_header2 -> Label(-text=>"Molex Automation Tool");
    $frame_header2 -> grid(-row=>1,-column=>1);
    $header2 -> grid(-row=>1,-column=>1);

    my $frame_sub_header2 = $mw2->Frame();
    my $sub_header2 = $frame_sub_header2 -> Label(-text=>"Tasks Region Wise");
    $frame_sub_header2 -> grid(-row=>2,-column=>1);
    $sub_header2 -> grid(-row=>2,-column=>1);

    MainLoop;
}
```

I have reduced the code and only put the relevant lines. Now please let me know why I can't kill the main window opened in sub welcome_window() in the sub outside(). Currently what it does is it closes the main windows during the sleep command but as soon as I open the main windows of the second_windows, the windows of welcome_window also reappears.

> Got the above code working now, there was some issue in the logic
>   which was calling the welcome_window again. Thank you all for your
>   help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have more than one MainWindow. Create a Toplevel window for the initial one, use `withdraw` to hide the real main window at the start, make it reappear with `deiconify`:

```
my $mw = MainWindow->new;
my $tl = $mw->Toplevel;
$tl->protocol(WM_DELETE_WINDOW => sub {
    $mw->deiconify;
    $tl->DESTROY;
});
$mw->withdraw;
MainLoop();
```

Comment: Can I make this withdaw function work from outside the MainLoop()? Currently I am not able to do it.

Comment: Also I have separate MainLoop for each window? Does this makes any difference

Comment: I don't understand the first question. Try to ask a new question, not a comment. You can probably have two MainLoops with two different MainWindows, just make sure not to define the second one before the first loop ends.

Comment: I have added the additional information in my question above. Please let me know the solution for it.

Comment: Your code does nothing. How do you call the functions?